# Table View Data Storage and Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring

I am trying to store some data in a table view controller achieved from an integer and a text string in a normal view controller.

Complete description:

A new random integer will be generated each time you tap a button. Basically the integer will then be visible (in the normal view controller) in a label. Then you can tap a "Save" button which basically will let you enter a string of text and then tap "Done". After tapping "Done", the text you entered, will be shown in a newly generated cell in the table view controller. The text you entered will be shown to the left and the integer (which was saved as well when tapping done) will be shown to the right in the cell. I am just setting up the cell style as "Right Detail" in order to do this.

I guess this is pretty simple to do but I haven't found the completely right way to do it yet.

Hope you guys have a couple of good ideas on how to set this up.

Comment: If you provide us with code showing what you have tried so far, we can help you learn instead of just giving you a solution

Comment: I was looking mostly for like ideas on how to set it up. Not just correcting the code. So far I have only set up the table view controller, set up the style of the cell and written a couple of lines of code. (this is only a "small" part of the app so I've written a lot more code on the other features in the app). This is currently the code I've written regarding this implementation.                              the .h file: '@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    
    IBOutlet UILabel *Display;
    
    NSString *Saved; }'

Comment: the .m file: -(IBAction)Save:(id)sender{
    
    Display.text = Saved;
    
}

Comment: `-(IBAction)Save:(id)sender{
    
    Display.text = Saved;
    
}
`

Comment: My basic question is how to take the two text strings and use their value/text in order to display them in a table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a separate class to hold the data. Lets call this a RandomNumberList. This data object will have an array of RandomNumbers (another custom class). RandomNumber will have two properties: name, and number.

The table view data source should use this data object to display each cell. Every time the user hits save you should add a RandomNumber to the array on RandomNumberList. You will then have to tell the table view that there is a new row by using `-[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: One more question. Does the Table View Content need to be switched over to Static Cells instead of Dynamic Protoypes in order to make this work? I am asking since I am experiencing this weird problem. When I switch over to Static Cells (which I usually use when using table view controllers) it places the Cells ABOVE the navigation bar instead of the cells underneath the navigation bar. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: That sounds like an issue with how you are placing the tableview itself. If you are using a navigation controller, you should have no problems because the navbar is always kept above all views within the root view controller. If you are manually placing a nav bar, just make sure it is above the tableview.

Comment: I am placing it manually but everytime I try to drag it above the cells it just appears underneath them instead. I am only experiencing this problem when using the static cells but of course this does not happen with dynamic prototypes. Is it okay to use dynamic prototypes (I always use static cells when working with table views)?

Comment: I am also experiencing problems with integrating the array part of the code. Could you please give me an example of what you described previously? Thanks.

Comment: The way that you create the cells does not matter. I recommend using a navigation controller instead of manually placing a nav bar. It makes it more expandable in the future and it lets UIKit handle the type of issue you are describing and other things as well.

Comment: Ok. I will use a navigation controller instead.                          Can you help with the array integration? It would be absolutely awesome if you could provide some example code for what you described earlier regarding the array integration.

Comment: There are thousands of examples online. Apple themselves have a good example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW18